# I want to add a test report file as attachment in jira using CI tools like Jenkins, please guide me on this

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jira

- I want to add a test report file as attachment in jira using CI tools
  like Jenkins, please guide me on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the plugin [Jira Pipeline Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jira-steps/)

Now, you can make use of [jiraUploadAttachment](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira-steps/#jirauploadattachment-jira-steps-attach-a-file-from-workspace-to-an-issue) step, which uploads a file from worksapce to issue.

Now, below is the scripted pipeline step example to upload a file to JIRA:

```yaml
node {
  stage('JIRA') {
    def attachment = jiraUploadAttachment idOrKey: 'TEST-REPORT', file: 'test_report.txt'
    echo attachment.data.toString()
  }
}
```

> **Note:** Hope that you have already configured JIRA SITE details under **Manage Jenkins >> Configure System >> Jira**